# How to split up integer value?

Tags: php

how i can split up integer value like '3452' as 3 4 5 2 and assign each integer to an alphabet like 'B = 3', 'G = 4', 'Q = 5', 'U = 2' as we required and then merge these alphabets like 'BGQU' and return this string and use it outside of function. Please tell me if there is any option.

Comment: use implode() function

Comment: echo implode($split_code);

Comment: looks like you have split some text getting sequence of numbers and now you want to join them again. What's the sense?

Comment: I take it that what you posted is pseudo-code. I've never seen a function without `()`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php - A class yes, but not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your code is incorrect (see your function has no `()`) Try [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) like,

```
function get_value($split_code) {
    return implode('',$split_code);
}
```

or just use,

```
implode($split_code);
```

Comment: oh i just forgot to add parentheses during writing question.

Comment: how i can split up integer value like '3452' as 3 4 5 2 and assign each integer to an alphabet like 'B = 3', 'G = 4', 'Q = 5', 'U = 2' and then merge these alphabets like 'BGQU'. Please tell me if u have any suggestion.

Comment: If you got an answer for the question(before edit the original) and you want something different than this then ask another question on SO. My suggestion is undo your original question, otherwise SO users will not able to understand the answer for your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array.

Note: The implode() function accept its parameters in either order. However, for consistency with explode(), you should use the documented order of arguments.

SYNTAX:

```
implode(separator,array)

$split_code = array(2,4,3,5,7);
echo implode($split_code); 

function get_value($split_code) {
return implode($split_code);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is your friend:

```
$split_code = array(2,4,3,5,7);
$values = implode($split_code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:-

```
function joinArray(){
  var $split_code =array(2,4,3,5,7);
  $joined_string=implode("",$split_code);
  return $joined_string;
}
```

Comment: how i can split up integer value like '3452' as 3 4 5 2 and assign each integer to an alphabet like 'B = 3', 'G = 4', 'Q = 5', 'U = 2' as we required and then merge these alphabets like 'BGQU' and return this string and use it outside of function. Please tell me if there is any option